# Get client MAC Address (NIC) in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to get client PC's MAC Address (Network Interface Card) in asp.net c# ?

Comment: This is a very common question. I recommend a google search, `site:stackoverflow.com your search term here` to find if your question has been asked before. Also, Stack Overflow has a pretty good search, and you can always use that.  Also, the "Ask a question" title box pops up a list of questions that may already have your answer. I know both of those questions are in that list.

Comment: The dupe you chose, that's for the local machine, @George. The OP is trying to get the *remote* machine's MAC address.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The good news is that the second question also has the answer. :-) I can't fix it without re-opening and reclosing the question.

Comment: OP, just a note: you probably don't need the client machine's MAC address. Call it me reading your mind. :). You might ask about the higher-level requirement you have - *why* do you think you need the MAC address? As George says, make sure you search before you ask about that.